# Failed to create Glue Crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to create a Glue Crawler with an IAM role that has AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSGlueServiceRole and AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess policies, but when I click "Create crawler" it shows the error message at the top:

[image: crawler]

I tried creating with an admin user and a root user, but both got the same error message. By the way, the bucket has SSE-S3 encryption. Is it related to Lake Formation or encryption ? I've read similar questions here but couldn't find the solution. I am new to AWS so I have little knowledge in it. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That might not be enough information to help you out. But try looking at Cloudtrail menu and check the history of actions on your account and try to find out which one has had an error (for most cases it will tell which IAM action is missing from your user).

However, if you tried to do this with the root user, it could imply that this account may have restricted permissions (e.g. via SCPs - organization level restrictions), although these usually come with an encrypted message in the error on the console.